# Is there any example of pooling Ethereum to invest in a company’s operations?

Tags: dao, staking

I was wondering if there is some structure that bridges the gap between pooling or collective staking of a cryptocurrency, and traditional investment in which you and others fund the operation of a company, and sometimes possibly have a minor influence on the company’s choices.

For example, imagine if you wanted to try to produce a natural resource, such as timber, or energy, or infrastructure, such as servers. Perhaps there could be a company running those operations, and you can fund their business, giving them liquidity to continue develop their profitability, in exchange for a stake in the company’s worth, and possibly a minor role in deciding how the business should be?

Maybe this is already normal, I just wasn’t yet familiar with it? I think the idea is something like a DAO, but maybe with a few differences.

1. “Leadership” not does have to be totally democratically distributed over every single member of the DAO. It’s ok if the center of the operation works more like a normal company with hierarchical leadership.
2. I guess I don’t really know that much about DAO’s, i.e., if there are some where both membership as well as goals have nothing to do with money; for example, it’s just a blockchain-managed organization whose decisions are based on blockchain elections and smart contracts? Whereas my idea is like a DAO but your level of inclusion is directly the amount of money you put in, like investment; and the point of the DAO is to generate profit via a commercial operation.

Any examples of this?

Or, possibly - if possible - the same thing except even the company’s operations are decentralized and a person could even contribute to the company’s production of a good perhaps by completing some task that the DAO/company has bountied, like, “please help us by doing this…” (something that an employee would conventionally do, in a company).

The first one interests me more than the second - a commercial enterprise with centralized design, but blockchain-invested.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, and yes.

1. No, there is no infrastructure, that can enforce a company pays its profits to you.  The only way this would really be 100% enforcable is if all their revenue came on chain.
2. There are existing examples of Tokenization however, which,  tokenizes resources such as Carbon.  However this is a tokenization of the resource itself.
3. Yes, you can create an implicit contract, for a company to pay its profits out to their token.  It would be just as simple as having a token, then the company drives the token price up by buying their token with the profits and then burning all they bought.
4. Alternatively you can tokenize shares of your company, and then pay dividents.  That would be more complex still would not really guarantee profits, as alot of infrastructure would have to be put inplace and a vote could pass which would modify the divident ratio.